# UI-Grid, angular-date-picker-polyfill - month name in local language

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I implemented UI-Grid control with column which includes date picker inside well. I am using angular-date-picker-polyfill, it works very nice, buy have always month name displayed in english, even I have different language set in Chrome. Also week day start is Sunday and I would like to have Monday at first position.

angular-date-picker-polyfill is from: https://github.com/adamalbrecht/angular-date-picker-polyfill

I have column template like:

```
rejestrator.columnTemplates.dayCellEditable =
'<div class="column-day">' +
    '<span ng-model="row.entity.day" aa-date-input task-id="row.entity.id">{{ COL_FIELD | date:"yyyy-MM-dd" }}</span>'+
'</div>';
```